# How to obtain maximum counts by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Using tidyverse, I would like to obtain the maximum count of events (e.g., dates) by group. Here is a minimum reproducible example:

Data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5),
                 event = c(12, 6, 1, 7, 13, 9, 4, 8, 2, 5, 11, 3, 10, 14))
```

The following code produces the desired output, but seems overly complicated:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(count) %>% 
  slice_max(count, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE)
```

Is there a simpler/better way? The following works, but `top_n` has been superseded by `slice_max` and it is [recommended](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html) that the latter be used instead.

```
df %>%
count(id) %>% 
distinct(n) %>% # to remove tied values 
top_n(1)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the maximum number of events by group (where `id` is the grouping variable), then:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(max_n_events = max(event))
```

If instead you basically do not consider the specific values in the `event` column and only look at the `id` column, the solution proposed by @Josh above can also be written as follows:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% count() %>% ungroup() %>% summarise(max(n))
```

Comment: This is a useful simplification. The example data was admittedly a bit artificial. In my actual code, prior to the `group_by` step, the `event` column is used with id to remove duplicates.

Comment: @mtnrambler ok I understand now. I edit the answer accordingly. I am glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want something with fewer steps, you could try base R `table()` to get the counts in a vector and then take the `max()`. By default it returns the max value only once even if it appears a few times in the vector.

```
max(table(df$id))
```

```
[1] 4
```

Or if you want it in tidyverse style

```
df$id %>% 
  table() %>% 
  max()
```

Comment: This is a useful reminder of the value of `table` in similar situations.